# Delete user with soft delete

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to delete user with soft delete I have added in table

```
$table->softDeletes($column = 'deleted_at', $precision = 0);
```

And in model
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use SoftDeletes;

In controller

```
   public function close(User $user)
    {
        $user->delete();
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Route

```
   <form method="POST" action="{{ route('close') }}">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
        <button class="profile-delete-button classic-button">
            Delete Account
        </button>
    </form>
```

It's redirect's to main page but in users deleted_at column null.
So what's I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't `route('close')` have a `$user` parameter somewhere in it?

Comment: yes thanks it was id problem

Answer (score 1):

add `SoftDeletes` trait to your `User` model

your code should be as such

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The route should be

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('close', ['user' => $user]) }}">
```